# MIniHBaseCluster shutting down with java.lang.RuntimeException: Master not initialized after 200000ms

Tags: java, unit-testing, hbase, java-17, hbasetestingutility

To give a background, our project uses bigtable. For unit testing, we are using the package hbase-testing-util:2.2.3 for creating a local mini hbase cluster.
Our code base is in Java 8 and I'm trying to migrate it to Java 17. While doing so, I'm encountering the following error on running the unit tests (in java 17).

```
Starting hbase testing utility failed: java.io.IOException: Shutting down
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.init(MiniHBaseCluster.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.<init>(MiniHBaseCluster.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniHBaseCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1071)
    at com.yawasa.server.testing.TestingUtility.init(TestingUtility.java:165)
```

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.yawasa.server.BabelFishStringValueTest.before(BabelFishStringValueTest.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Shutting down
    at com.yawasa.server.testing.TestingUtility.init(TestingUtility.java:195)
    at com.yawasa.server.testing.TestingUtility.<clinit>(TestingUtility.java:713)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Shutting down
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.init(MiniHBaseCluster.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.<init>(MiniHBaseCluster.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniHBaseCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1071)
    at com.yawasa.server.testing.TestingUtility.init(TestingUtility.java:165)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Master not initialized after 200000ms
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.waitForEvent(JVMClusterUtil.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.startup(JVMClusterUtil.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.startup(LocalHBaseCluster.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MiniHBaseCluster.init(MiniHBaseCluster.java:259)
    ... 52 more
```

There is another set of stacktrace for ~360 threads that indicate that the threads are waiting for some event. They look like this:

```
Thread 340 (master/localhost:0.Chore.1):
  State: TIMED_WAITING
  Blocked count: 0
  Waited count: 3
  Stack:
    java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Thread 341 (snapshot-hfile-cleaner-cache-refresher):
  State: TIMED_WAITING
  Blocked count: 0
  Waited count: 1
  Stack:
    java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:563)
    java.base@17.0.7/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:516)
```

I haven't been able to find any info for this particular issue.

I tried upgrading the library to 2.3.0+ version but that is leading to a jar hell much before this code path is hit, so I'm not sure if resolving the jar hell will resolve the complete issue.